# Can nightwatch.js use usingServer from selenium-webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, remotewebdriver

I have a suite of tests using local drivers built with nightwatch. Works well.

I am running a basic test using Perfecto Mobile and selenium-webdriver. It works with this example.(https://community.perfectomobile.com/series/20208/posts/1002862)

I am trying to connect my suite of nightwatch test to perfecto, but can't start selenium. If this is the url of the selenium server.

```
var url = "https://mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub";
```

I tried a few ways to set it up under nightwatch config, but can't make it work.

```
"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "host" : "mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub"
}
```

Is there an equivalent to **usingServer** in nightwatch? I haven't seen anything in the docs.

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
  usingServer(url).
  withCapabilities(capabilities).
  build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was the setup needed.

```
"test_settings" : {
  "perfecto" : {
    "use_ssl": true,
    "default_path_prefix": "/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub",
    "selenium_port"  : 443,
    "selenium_host"  : "mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com",
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "xxx",
      "deviceName": "xxx",
      "user": "xxx@xxx.xxx",
      "password": "xxx",
      "platformName": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

The important part that didn't work at the time of writing the question: the **default_path_prefix** was not customizable.

**/wd/hub** was the default prefix. But I really needed **/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub**.

Two days later, this commit was introduced. It is available in 0.9.5 release.

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/commit/aa24c2c2334c42388318498f654d8fe2957967d1