# Can Nightwatch.js connect to selenium server with https protocol?

Tags: selenium-grid, nightwatch.js

I am experimenting with running our Nightwatch test suites against cloud-based browser testing services. For now, I would be running Nightwatch from my local machine, specifying the test settings like `selenium_port` and `selenium_host` to connect to selenium on the cloud service's system. The test sends passwords for logging into the system under test, so I don't want this to go across the internet in clear text.

I don't see any mention of something like `selenium_protocol` or `selenium_scheme` (http or https) in the [Nightwatch docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file).

By comparison, [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html) has a `protocol` configuration property that I have set to `"https"` for our WebdriverIO tests.

Is there a way for Nightwatch to communicate with the selenium server with https?

Comment: Both Saucelabs and Browserstack have proxy tunnels to connect directly to your local system. https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing | https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `use_ssl` to `true` in the options, and `selenium_port` to `443`.

e.g.

```
   "test_settings" : {

        "default": {
          "launch_url" : "https://yoururl.com",
          "selenium_host" : "hub-cloud.browserstack.com",
          "selenium_port" : 443,
          "use_ssl": true
        }
   }
```

(I just had to do the same thing, and it doesn't look like it's documented)

Here's the source:

Getting the option: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/375f578509e0d3ba819b7f1ef466159874d58086/lib/index.js#L114

Adding the setting: 
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/375f578509e0d3ba819b7f1ef466159874d58086/lib/index.js#L124-L126

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/375f578509e0d3ba819b7f1ef466159874d58086/lib/http/request.js#L218

Using HTTPS: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/375f578509e0d3ba819b7f1ef466159874d58086/lib/http/request.js#L99

Comment: This is throwing: "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?"

Comment: This might be needed as well, depending upon the cloud service that you are using. "default_path_prefix": "/wd/hub"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867425/can-nightwatch-js-use-usingserver-from-selenium-webdriver